# Count of unique values in part of column only when matching multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to learn to use SUMPRODUCT to count unique values based on multiple criteria and can't quit get it right.  Wildcard does not work on sumproduct.  And some cells may be blank.  (I am on Mac Excel v 16.33, if that makes a difference.)

I need to count the unique date values in A6:A100 where E6:E100 is any one of these:

```
P CD       Project Cert K9
P UCD      Project Uncert K9
P O        Project Overhead
P S        Project Support
```

[image: example data]

Update:  I *think* I got it. (Please ignore the different row numbers.)  If you have a more efficient / elegant solution, please provide it.  I'd like to improve this!

```
=SUMPRODUCT((IF(LEFT(E20:E100,1)="P", TRUE,FALSE))/(IF(COUNTIFS(A20:A100,A20:A100,E20:E100,"*Project*")=0,1,COUNTIFS(A20:A100,A20:A100&"",E20:E100,"*Project*"))))
```

Comment: Can you  please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1519009/edit) to include the formula you have tried so far?

Comment: Assuming the string to look for *always* include the word "Project" in them, you can use: `ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PROJECT",E16:E100))` to test for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numerator of your *<condition>/<countifs>* division is `LEFT(E6:E99)="P"`¹ then you should be duplicating that condition in the COUNTIFS, not replacing it with a wildcard search for `"*project*"`.

Add the logical reverse of the numerator condition to the denominator. This avoids `#DIV/0!` errors.

Your `IF(LEFT(E20:E100,1)="P", TRUE,FALSE)` is redundant. The `LEFT(E20:E100,1)="P"` is a logical (aka *boolean*) statement in itself You don't need to check if it is TRUE/FALSE then supply a TRUE/FALSE.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(E6:E99)="P")/(COUNTIFS(A6:A99,A6:A99,E6:E99,"P*")+(LEFT(E6:E99)<>"P")))
```

[image]

---

¹ <sub>The LEFT function defaults to a single character so LEFT(A6:A99) is the same as LEFT(A6:A99, 1).</sub>